# Refresh of nested Routes - React Router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Question is simple and I did not find any relevant setup to mine.

So here goes the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-refresh-gdxcz?file=/src/views/term/index.tsx) to the actual issue.

Now, I will brief.

If you navigate to `root/term/` and then to Route 2 component from the app in Sandbox link and finally hit refresh, the component disappears. All I'm left with is AppHeader.

The reason being that the route match happens at Component `App.tsx` and it does not find any relevant match. Fair Enough!

I can counter this by adding the specified routes at the root level and also flattening them all.

Something like

```
<Route path="/root/term/" />
<Router path="/root/term/route1" />
<Route path="/root/term/route2" />
```

But my question is that if I really have to leverage the dynamic routing with nested routes, I should not add all routes in one place (root i.e App here). That is what React router 4 prefers us to do.

The only issue arises in the case of a refresh.

On Searching common solution that pops up is to detect refresh and prevent reload. But even that [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) is experimental -

So what would be the best solution to approach dynamic, declarative and nested routing in React router 4 to contain page refresh and possibly redirect to the immediate parent if a refresh does happens?

In this case, I would like do redirect to `/root/term` when any of route1, route2, route3 under `term` are refreshed.

Hope, I made my question clear!

**Update** - @Nguyen's answer pointed me towards the right direction.
Ony change required was to remove `exact` from parent `<Route path="/term" />`. Child routes can still have an exact match.

Updated [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-refresh-dmlf2?file=/src/views/term/index.tsx)

Good learning for `exact` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

If the path is another router, it should never be an exact Route. The basename of the child router should include full path i.e /root/term

Here's the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-refresh-f5ied) to my version of router. Hope that helps!

Comment: You pointed me towards the right direction but your explanation can be improved. We just need to remove `exact` from Parent route and child routes can have `exact`